# Combining json files in python

Tags: python

I have 3 json files as below:

test1.json:

```
{"item":"book1","price":"10.00","location":"library"}
```

test2.json:

```
{"item":"book2","price":"15.00","location":"store"}
```

test3.json:

```
{"item":"book3","price":"9.50","location":"store"}
```

I have this code:

```
import json
import glob

result = ''
for f in glob.glob("*.json"):
    with open (f, "r") as infile:
        result += infile.read()

with open("m1.json", "w") as outfile:
    outfile.writelines(result)
```

I get the following output:

```
{"item":"book1","price":"10.00","location":"library"} 
{"item":"book2","price":"15.00","location":"store"}
{"item":"book3","price":"9.50","location":"store"}
```

Is it possible to get each file as a new line separated by a comma like below?

```
{"item":"book1","price":"10.00","location":"library"},  <-- line 1
{"item":"book2","price":"15.00","location":"store"},    <-- line 2
{"item":"book3","price":"9.50","location":"store"}      <-- line 3
```

Comment: FYI your desired result in not valid JSON.

Comment: While producing your desired output *is* possible, it is not JSON.

Comment: Maybe you're not looking for a JSON string, but rather an array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others commented, your expected result is invalid json.
But if you really want the format, use `str.join()` is more convenient.

```py
jsons = []
for f in glob.glob("*.json"):
    with open (f, "r") as infile:
        jsons.append(infile.read())
result = ',\n'.join(jsons)
```

`infile.read()` gets the string, `d = json.loads(infile.read())` can get a real json object(`dict`).

To write a valid *combined* json(of type `list(of dict)`), just write `s = json.dumps(jsons)` to file.